# Shared Preference when Application starts

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In android can I create a SharedPreference with default values when Application Installs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

yes you can create a sharedPreference with a default value in android...

```
    SharedPreferences myPreference = this.getSharedPreferences("myPreference", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor myPreferenceEditor = myPreference.edit();
    myPreferenceEditor.putString("Name", "Android");
    myPreferenceEditor.commit();
```

and you can get this value by:

```
    SharedPreferences myPreference = this.getSharedPreferences("myPreference", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    String name = myPreference.getString("Name", "nothing");
```

Comment: in your code , whenever I start the application it'll set sharedpreference to default value right??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can create default values on Install.
Maybe you could do it when application start

1) define xml preferences with default values like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/server_preferences" >

        <EditTextPreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_server_preferences"
            android:dialogTitle="@string/dialog_title_server_preference"
            android:key="server"
            android:summary="@string/summary_server_preferences"
            android:title="@string/title_server_preferences" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/application_preferences" >

        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="@string/default_decimals_preferences"
            android:entries="@array/decimals_list_preference"
            android:entryValues="@array/decimals_list_preference"
            android:key="decimals"
            android:summary="@string/summary_decimals_preferences"
            android:title="@string/title_decimals_preferences" >
        </ListPreference>
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

2) On your application or homeActivity you call

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
```